# I accidentally own /etc/ on user ubuntu in aws ec2

Tags: 14.04, sudo

I accidentally own `/etc/` on user Ubuntu in aws ec2
I owned `/etc/` and now this message comes up whenever I used `sudo`:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 1000, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I have been finding answers here yesterday until now and I haven't found any solution that doesn't require stopping an instance.

**(This is not the same as the 'another question' posted, why? because he can still run 'sudo' base on the comments I read, and this is a cloud server )**

This is my `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: if you don't have password on root account and any sudo session opened left then you're locked. Try to execute root exploit if your OS is vulnerable to some public known CVE.

Comment: @muru I disagree, because the machine and the problem(well has some similarity) have some differences actually. If there is some chance I can undo this without actually stopping an instance can be a solution.

Comment: Can you run `pkexec`, or as insider says, do you have a root session open? If so, there might be a chance. If not, no chance.

Comment: @muru aww, this happened yesterday i lost all root when i close my client machine, but i think i have found a way. Im still doing it...

Comment: @insider i can vim and write using '!' to override sudoers file(does this help?) , it gives me hope now. what else can i do?

Comment: Not to rain on your parade, but considering you own all of `/etc`, it's hardly surprising that you can edit files in it. The problem is changing ownerships - which can only be done root. As before, can you run `pkexec`?

Comment: @muru no, it asked for password.

Comment: @david you don't know your password? Ah, of course. `/etc/passwd` and `shadow` will also be owned by you - so they will be ignored as well, presumably.

Comment: this is a cloud-server we didnt put passwords on it actually. we just connect securely using ssh.

Comment: @muru aw really? anyways I can only write what can i do with this disadvantage?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to boot a live cd and run

```
sudo chown root:root -R /media/$USER/*/etc
```

You will need to open the folder in the file browser to mount the disk

Comment: This does not help either, I can't actually use 'sudo'.

Comment: I suggested to boot using live CD of Ubuntu. After doing this you will have sudo access

Answer (score 0):

Run:
    vim /etc/sudoers

You will find a line similar to:

```
$ROOT: $ALL
```

Insert this line after:

```
$ <your_uid> : $ALL
```

But you need root permissions to do this.

Comment: actually its not the same here it is:

`# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`

Comment: i can vim and write using '!' to override , it gives me hope now. what else can i do?

Comment: Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
ee209195 ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
~

Comment: what do i do with it?

Answer (score -1):

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
**ee209195 ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL    # TODO ADD THIS LINE With your uid**

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: I tried it , my uid is 1000 but it doesnt work 
`1000 ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`

tried to vim it and :wq! to override write read-only file